# thread inheritance in java

Tags: java, multithreading, inheritance

```
   class ThreadInherit extends Helper implements Runnable 
   {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
                System.out.println("Hello World");
                Thread.sleep(500);
                if (i == 10) {
                    Notify();
                    Wait();
                }                       
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Thread_Inherit1 extends ThreadInherit 
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Wait();
            for(int i = 1; i<=20; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Welcome");
                Thread.sleep(550);
            }
            Notify();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
    }

    class Helper
    {
    public synchronized void Wait() throws InterruptedException
    {
        wait();
    }
    public synchronized void Notify() throws InterruptedException
    {
        notify();
    }
    }
    public class Inheritance_Class {

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {   
        Thread_Inherit1 u = new Thread_Inherit1();
        Thread_Inherit1 t = new ThreadInherit();
        t.run();
        u.run();

    }

}
```

So I have this code...
I have a problem with this line

```
  Thread_Inherit1 t = new ThreadInherit();
```

It cannot be converted into Thread_Inherit1.
Suggestions of Eclipse:

1.Add cast to Thread_Inherit1 (I did, but still giving me error)
2. Change to ThreadInherit. (probably, not the solution)

Any help?

Comment: `B extends A` means that `B` **is an** `A`, not vice versa.

Comment: Thank you. :) I tried to change it. But why is Thread_Inherit1 not running? Only the first thread

Comment: Please follow [java](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info#conventions) naming conventions: it's `ThreadInherit1`, not `Thread_Inherit1`. It's `wait` and `notify`, not `Wait` and `Notify`. And `Inheritance_Class` should be `InheritanceClass`.

Comment: Thank you. This is just for testing. :) Thank you for reminding.

Comment: "just for testing" sorry, not an excuse.

Answer (score 1):

I think you really want:

```
 ThreadInherit t = new Thread_Inherit1();
```

It makes more sense to assign the subclass to have the type of the super type. The other way is probably not what you want.

Also, to start the threads, you want to call `start()`, not `run()` directly. Try this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Thread_Inherit1());
Thread u = new Thread(new ThreadInherit());

t.start();
u.start();
```

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I am so careless. Thank you. :) I tried to run my program changing it to ThreadInherit t = new Thread_Inherit1(); Still the first thread is the only one running..not the second thread

Comment: new ThreadInherit().start(); new new Thread_Inherit1().start(); should run both "types" of threads. Don't call run() directly.

Comment: oh. I tried t.run and u.run which are the new ThreadInherit1() and new ThreadInherit...but the only thread that is running is ThreadInherit.

Comment: Try calling start() instead of run().

Comment: but there is no start method in the intellisense on both Threads

Comment: You will need to wrap it in a thread. Look at my updated answer.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. But the error said, I may want to change its type to Thread_Inherit1 or ThreadInherit(both Threads). I changed it. I tried to change its type and the error is: I may want to remove that argument or I shall create constructor. :(

Comment: oh I'm sorry..It's my error. I tried to your again. Still the first one is only running

Answer (score 1):

Your code has:

```
class Thread_Inherit1 extends ThreadInherit
```

... and your problem line is:

```
Thread_Inherit1 t = new ThreadInherit();
```

The trouble is that things are backwards. ThreadInherit IS NOT a thread_Inherit1. I think the line you meant to write is:

```
ThreadInherit t = new Thread_Inherit1();
```

Hopefully that'll solve your problem.