# Second Thread does not give an output (java)

Tags: java, multithreading, inheritance

```
class firstThread extends Helper1
{
        Thread thread_1 = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
                        System.out.println("Hello World");
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                        if (i == 10) {
                            Notify();
                            Wait();
                        }                       
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }); 
}
class secondThread extends firstThread 
{
    Thread thread_2 = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {   
                Wait();
                for(int i = 1; i<=20; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Welcome");
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
                Notify();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

class Helper1
{
    public synchronized void Wait() throws InterruptedException
    {
        wait();
    }
    public synchronized void Notify() throws InterruptedException
    {
        notify();
    }
}
public class InheritanceClass {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Thread f = new Thread(new firstThread().thread_1);
        Thread s = new Thread(new secondThread().thread_2);
        f.start();
        s.start();
    }



}
```

Only the first Thread has an output. Please try my code. I don't know why it happens.
The second thread does not give output, I suppose it's because of Wait() in the secondThread, I don't know what to do.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

Comment: You [just posted this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974206/thread-inheritance-in-java). I reminded you of coding and naming conventions. You ignored them. -1.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the following code:

```
class Helper1
{
    public synchronized void Wait() throws InterruptedException
    {
        wait();
    }
    public synchronized void Notify() throws InterruptedException
    {
        notify();
    }
}
```

Above, the `wait()` and `notify()` calls are equivalent to `this.wait()` and `this.notify()`. However, `thread1` and `thread2` are separate objects so they are not ever going to communicate via this method.

In order for communication to occur, you need a shared lock object. For example:

```
Object lock = new Object();
firstThread = new firstThread(lock);
secondThread = new secondThread(lock);
```

and synchronizations like:

```
void wait(Object lock) {
    synchronized(lock) {
        lock.wait();
    }
}

void notify(Object lock) {
    synchronized(lock) {
        lock.notify();
    }
}
```

*Disclaimer:* I would never do this personally, however it does answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

This code is really confusing, which is making it hard to see the underlying problem.

- You should never start a class with a lower-case letter since it makes it look like a method/field name (e.g. `firstThread`).
- I'm pretty sure `Wait` and `Notify` have no reason to be `synchronized`.
- Why does `secondThread` inherit from `firstThread`??? Actually, why do you have those two classes at all? You should just make an anonymous inner class from `Helper1` or something.

Anyway, the problem is that when you call `Notify()` in thread1 it notifies *itself*, not thread2.

Comment: @user2438658 - Having your anonymous inner classes extend `Helper1` _is_ inheritance. Having `secondThread` extend `firstThread` is just silly because you don't actually want a `thread_1` field in `secondThread`—but you have one because of your screwy class hierarchy. If nothing else, you should change `secondThread` to directly extend `Helper1`.